# Datagrid with Checkbox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

suppose consider in datagrid i have two text box when i fill records to it then i ill press tab key then another row automatically generated so how can i delete multiple rows using checkbox in datagrid not in gridview

Comment: You should probably tag a language and/or framework to this question. Flex? .NET?

Comment: Simply iterate through each row which is checked

Answer (score 0):

> int i = (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); while ((i >= 0)) {    i = (i -
>   1); foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in DataGridView1.Rows)  {         if
>   (dr.Cells("check").Value == false)  {
>             DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dr);      }   } }